# Annotating Points in Scatterplot with Logarithmic Axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I use `matplotlib` to produce a scatterplot of a few points. Each point should be annotated with a label. I tried to place the labels randomly on a circle around the point coordinates. However, I do not get satisfactory results. One major problem is that the y-axis needs to be scaled logarithmically.

What is an easy way to place the labels so that they do not overlap and have visually a constant distance from their points?

```
import random
import math

algos = [plm, plm2, plp, plmr2, plmr, clutbb, rg, cggc, cggci, epp_plm, louvain, epp_plm2, epp_plmr2]
labels = ["PLM(o)", "PLM", "PLP", "PLMR", "PLMR(o)", "CLU_TBB", "RG", "CGGC", "CGGCi", "EPP(o)", "Louvain", "EPP_PLM", "EPP_PLMR"]
scores = [paretoScore(algo, plm2) for algo in algos]

def labelcoord(coord, r, s):
    (x, y) = coord
    phi = random.uniform(0, 2 * math.pi)
    return (x + r * math.cos(phi), y + s * math.sin(phi))


scatter(*(zip(*scores)), color="Green")
xlabel("modularity score")
yscale("symlog")
ylabel("time score")
for (label, score) in zip(labels, scores):
    annotate(label, xy=score, xytext=labelcoord(score, 0.02, 10),
             fontsize=12,
             arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', color="lightgray", connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))
```

[image]